# iOS 7 + iPad: UISearchBar causes navigation bar content to be mixed with status bar

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar, statusbar

### This happens only on iPad:

- Put a simple `UISearchBar` in a `UIViewController` with a
  `UINavigationController`
- [optional] Set bar tint color: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];`
- Run the app.
- Tap on search bar (triggers animation)
- Now status bar is mixed with the top of the navigation bar content (i.e. title, buttons)

Before tap:
[image]

After tapping the search bar:
[image]

The problem happens with any color, but using `[UIColor clearColor]` as in the photos attached makes it easier to see the issue.

Any solutions will be great, although I prefer something more elegant than hiding the navigation bar title and buttons each time.

### EDIT

This bug happens only when using the following code in `viewdidLoad`:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: Did you get a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround I used eventually:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        return self.searchDisplayController.isActive;

    return NO;
}
```

This way when user searches it hides the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got once the same issue. If you are using storyboards, check please that all the outlets are set:

[image]

That fixed the animation...

Comment: No, I have all delegates set.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem, and the fix turned out to be one line:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translucent = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The following code worked:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeTop;
```